# 800x480 H264 video not working on some devices

Tags: android, resolution, android-videoview, codec

I´m trying to play a video using a VideoView. The video plays fine on most devices, but when i run it on the HTC Hero or HTC Wildfire the video does not work. They´re not working in the stock Android mediaplayer either on those devices.

The video settings are 800x480 resolution, Codec: H264 - MPEG-4, framerate 25

Heres the Logcat erromessage: 01-28 10:34:48.950: ERROR/MediaPlayer(888): Error (1,-15)

Does anyone know if Hero/Wildfire have some limitations when it comes to playing 800x480 videos?

Preciate all your help :)

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

hi you are getting the following error:
const PVMFStatus PVMFErrNoResources = (-15);// means there are no resources available to be played.I can suggest try to 'hint' those files. you can also read [this](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/external/opencore/doc/mio_developers_guide.pdf)
.